# Difference between use = "txns" and use = "trades" in tradeStrats()?

Tags: r, algorithmic-trading, quantitative-finance, quantstrat

I'm backtesting a trading strategy using the `quantstrat` package, when generating trade statistics using the `tradeStats()` function, what does de `use =` argument changes if using `"txns"` instead of `"trades"` as the argument.

Answer (score 0):

The `tradeStats` function is in blotter...you can read the source here - https://github.com/braverock/blotter/blob/master/R/tradeStats.R. When using `"txns"` the PnL is derived from the portfolio object, which typically is marked daily to the close price. When using `"trades"` the PnL will be based on the round trip trade (at least one buy txn and one sell txn, for example) which could be longer or shorter than the period used in the txn PL calculation. For intraday and other high frequency strategies you probably want to use `"trades"` and for lower frequency strategies that trade over periods typically spanning more than 1 day you probably want to use `"txns"` so that you get the analysis based on a daily mark-to-market of your portfolio. HTH.